# Meaning of "a wisp in the ether"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase *a wisp in the ether*? Here is the whole paragraph:

> But Descartes believed Galen's explanation for humans as similar to
>   sheep could not be reconciled with the notion that humans were created
>   in God's image. He thought the mind stood separate from the physical
>   body as *a wisp in the ether* that could act on the body.

Comment: Did you look up the definitions of the words already?

Comment: @simchona, yes I did. I would be very happy to delete my question if it is already a widely known phrase among the native speaker. I just need more explanation.

Comment: I didn't mean to make you feel like this wasn't a valid question. I just wanted to make sure that you had done some research on your own, so that the question was on putting it all together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how widely used it is as a phrase (I don't think I've heard or seen it before), but it is fairly clear what it means.

*Wisp* is a very slight trace (wisp of smoke), or minute quantity (wisp of hair), or otherwise almost invisible (will-o'-wisp).

*Ether* would probably be better written *æther* and refers not to the family of chemical compounds but to the all encompassing substance that the Michelson-Morley experiment proved did not exist (some hundreds of years after Descartes time, of course).

Therefore, 'the mind stood separate from the physical body as a *wisp in the æether*' refers to the mind being like a will-o'-wisp that cannot really be seen, but can influence the body.  Mind is qualitatively different from the body, yet undetectable except through its effect on the body.

Comment: that is all I need. Thank you very much. The translator of the book translated wisp as stack. I am editing the text now (for another language), It seemed very confusing with the meaning of stack.

Comment: I can't think how you would derive 'stack' from 'wisp'; it seems a very odd translation, and would indeed be confusing.

Comment: thanks again. Do you think something like shadow in the ether would be close to the meaning?

Comment: Close, but a shadow can imply a solid body (and a light source) casting it, whereas a wisp denies solidity.  'Gossamer' has some of the right connotations; 'ghost' or 'spirit' or 'phantom' have some of the right connotations.  Maybe 'like a phantom in the æther' might work, if you can translate 'phantom' well.

Comment: well, I'll do my best. it is not that easy either :) thanks again, and again.

Comment: If 'shadow' translates and the alternatives don't, you're probably close enough not to matter.  'Disembodied shadow'?  Accurate but ugly; the original has a poetic cast to it, and 'disembodied' does not.  Good luck; choice of words is hard enough in English without struggling to get it into another language too.

Comment: disembodied shadows (bedensiz gölgeler) sounds very poetic, and I guess it'll save my life :)

Comment: Why the translator got it wrong -- wisp and stack are both quantities of hay. From the Free Online Dictionary; Wisp: "A small bunch or bundle, as of straw, hair, or grass." Stack: "A large, usually conical pile of straw or fodder arranged for outdoor storage." It still seems a very strange mistake to have made.

Comment: Although usually a "smoke stack" refers to the actual chimney or funnel, I think it is also used of the smoke itself. Maybe the translator was thinking of "stack" as an insubstantial thing, like smoke. Whatever - bad choice of word.