# What does "these things are in the ether" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, meaning

What does ["these things are in the ether"](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/us-news-blog/2012/may/14/parents-and-parenting-usa) mean?
The context of the sentence is

> My own daughters' names are Freya, a more popular name across the pond than in the US, and Calla, which last trended as a baby name in 1880. Although the week Freya was born we learned of two other baby Freyas in our Brooklyn neighborhood. And a former colleague also had a little girl named Calla. **So these things are in the ether somehow.**

Thank you.

Comment: Also see [What is the meaning of 'in the ether'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107853), which may be a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Something that's in the ether is still unclear, undecided or unexplained. It's not clear what "those things" specifically refers to..I haven't read the whole article.

Answer (score 1):

The author is under the assumption that the names of his/her daughters are rare for the times and places they were given. Having found coincidentally the same names had been given to other children in the area, the author concludes that the attribution of such an occurrence can only come from an unseen force that subtly guides everyone's actions (the ether).

Answer (score 1):

The "ether" is defined as the "fabric" of the universe. Often it is considered to be the so called universal source of all knowledge. Basically a euphemism for God, or at least a nod towards a supreme being.
The concept is that we are all somehow connected with or to this "source," and therfore predisposed to certain choices as a result.